# Can AngularJS work in Java EE MVC Architecture : JSP->Servlet->EJB3.1->Business Object->DAO

Tags: angularjs, rest, jakarta-ee, model-view-controller, mvvm

I have a quick question on considering AngularJS (current stable version - 1.3.9) for an upcoming application that we are building on an existing framework. The current framework has a Java EE MVC architecture and here are the current components mentioned in sequential order in which they get invoked:

1. View - JSPs: This layer gets as response Java Objects and we use `jsp:useBean` to access its properties and display on screen.
2. If any modifications are done on the page, it goes through a ControllerServlet i.e a Java file which has code to access the HttpRequest and HttpSession related information. The controller also does a lookup in JNDI to find the name of the bean to invoke based on the HttpRequest parameter name, e.g. PageId
3. Once the EJBBean lookup is returned, the controller invokes an EJB 3.1 "no-interview" view - These are Stateless Beans annotated with `@Stateless`
4. EJBBean classes then invoke BusinessObject classes, we call them "BO" which internally  gets referenced by the DAO interface
5. A DAO implementation class is the one which is responsible for CRUD operations

**Our Problems as of now:**

1. The view is tightly coupled to Java Objects that are returned from DAOs and since the response is not converted to JSON, a lot of scriptlet code is used to display their value (I know scriplets are oldskool, but being a legacy solution there is no choice)
2. jQuery is used to manipulate the DOM before sending it to the controller layer
3. View is not the official record of whats happening on the screen, unlike AngularJS where I could easily understand
4. Developers write custom CSS for different browsers manually

**Proposed Solution**

1. View shall be designed for the new application using AngularJS
2. Take advantage of Bootstrap css classes which has readily available CSS which can be combined with AngularJS
3. Each request goes to ControllerServlet using $http service to ensure we use existing MVC architecture i.e routing every request through Controller
4. EJB Layer to be RESTFul to return data in JSON Format
5. Viewport specific css code for responsive web design - i.e same screen should render on multiple devices and platforms

**Questions**:

1. Is the proposed solution feasible? What are the downsides?
2. Is it a good practice to reference EJB Bean classes as RESTFul services?
3. Do we get access to all the Java EE objects / interfaces using AngularJS? For e.g. HttpRequest, HttpSession, etc.
4. Will it help in performing better by switching to this architecture?
5. Question from Management - Why not stick with jQuery! - Probably the hardest of all the questions to convince the management of Angular's benefits

Hope you guys can help throw some suggestions

Comment: I think the coolest example of this can be found here: [Java EE 7 and WebSocket API for Java (JSR 356) with AngularJS on WildFly](http://mgreau.com/posts/2013/11/11/javaee7-websocket-angularjs-wildfly.html)

Answer (score 0):

i'm using `spring 4.0.1` , `hibernate 4.3.5` ,`jackson 1.9.2` , I'm creating a `RESTful` webservice that returns a data in `JSON` format and `angularjs` in front-end which is loosely coupled with back-end.

concerning your questions;

1. the solution is feasible of course , until now there no downsides
   except session management is tricky because Restful ws is stateless
   .
2. it's provide a very elegant feature that you can access all your
       functionality via any application web-client-side, desktop or
       mobile.
3. angular app is fully isolated from back-end app you can maintain
           requests and session in the server and respond with what you like in
           json format to angular
4. same as 2

i hope it's helpful

Comment: check that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28209311/angularjs-application-with-ejb-only